# Ghost output when displaying; Nested Linked list [C]

Tags: c, struct, linked-list

sorry for the long codes iam still new to c.. it just happens whenever i display back the data the activity data always have 1 more data inserted which makes my program to not respond.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct activity{
    int reps, calBurn;
    char aName[30];

    struct activity *ptrnexto;
};

struct activity *newptro, *curptro, *prevptro;

struct plan {
    char pName[30], focus;
    int recWieght;

    struct plan *ptrnext;
    struct activity *act;
};

struct plan *headptr, *newptr, *curptr, *prevptr;

int menu(int num);
int insertPlan ();
int displayPlans ();

int main()
{
    menu(1);
}
```

//menu func

```
int menu(int no)
{
    int choice;
    if (no==0){
        return 0;
    }
    while(no==1)
    {
        system("cls");
        printf("\n");
        printf("\t\t\t\t   Welcome!\n");
        printf("\t\t\t   Input a new fitness plan\t [1]\n"
               "\t\t\t   View ALL fitness plan\t [5]\n");
        printf("\n\t\t\t          -----------\n ");
        printf("\t\t\t   Choice: ");
        scanf("%d",&choice);
        fflush(stdin);
        system("cls");
        switch(choice)
        {
            case 1:
            {
                insertPlan ();
                break;
            }
            case 5:
            {
                displayPlans ();
                return 0;
                break;
            }
            default:
            {
                printf("Invalid key entry.");
                break;
            }

        }//end switch
        printf("\n\tDo you wish to return to menu?\n"
               "\tYes[1]\t\tNo[0]\n\t");
        printf("-->  ");
        scanf("%d",&no);
        return menu(no);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

//insert func

```
int insertPlan ()
{

    int pos=0,ch;
    newptr = (struct plan*)malloc(sizeof(struct plan));

    printf("\n Recomended Wieght : ");
    scanf(" %d",&newptr->recWieght);
    printf("\n Plan Name : ");
    scanf(" %s",&newptr->pName);
    printf("\nUpperBody(U)--LowerBody(L)--Abdomen(A)--Stamina(S) \nPlan Focus : ");
    scanf(" %c",&newptr->focus);
    printf("\n Put in the plans : ");
    while(ch!=0)
    {
        newptro= (struct activity*)malloc(sizeof(struct activity));
        pos = pos +1;
        printf("\nInsert in actvity %d",pos);
        printf("\n Activity Name : ");
        scanf("%s",&newptro->aName);
        printf("\n how many reps : ");
        scanf("%d",&newptro->reps);
        printf("\n estimated calory burn : ");
        scanf("%d",&newptro->calBurn);

        if (newptr->act==NULL)
        {
            newptr->act=newptro;
            newptro->ptrnexto=NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            newptro->ptrnexto=newptr->act;
            newptr->act=newptro;
        }
        printf("\n\tIs there anymore plans?\n"
               "\tYes[1]\t\tNo[0]\n\t");
        scanf("%d",&ch);
    }


    if (headptr==NULL)
    {
        headptr=newptr;
        newptr->ptrnext=NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        newptr->ptrnext=headptr;
        headptr=newptr;
    }
    return
 menu(1);
}
```

//display

```
int displayPlans ()
{
    int pos=0;
    if (headptr==NULL)
        printf("EMPTY LIST");
    else
    {
        curptr=headptr;
        while(curptr!=NULL)
        {
            pos=pos +1;
            printf("\n%d -%s \n",pos, curptr->pName);
            curptro=curptr->act;

            while(curptro!=NULL)
            {
                printf(" #%s --> %d", curptro->aName, curptro->reps);
                curptro=curptro->ptrnexto;
            }
            curptr=curptr->ptrnext;
        }
    }
}
```

fitnessCookie.c
fitnessCpCookie
Created by Asyraf Fuyu on 23/04/2017.
Copyright fitnessCookie© 2017 . All rights reserved.

here is the output after the display output is run from the menu that
[image: display output]

## notice: i did not input that last underlined with red data.

how does one input a smiley anyway..

Comment: Start by using a debugger to locate *where* the crash happens. Then check for uninitialized variables or structure members. But most importantly, don't try to write the whole program at once. Iterate, write small parts of it, step by step, testing that it works between each step. I also suggest you read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Iam using codeblocks it is built in with some debugging plugins. its been a week of rewriting the code and changing its structure over, and i think its a bout time i try to find help from professionals. theres more code but i identified the crash happens at display function when i try to display my activity structure, i suspect my insert or display maybe wrong but i put the main menu function in case overlooked.

Comment: Using uninitialize variable. `ch` at `while(ch!=0)`, `newptr->act` at `if (newptr->act==NULL)`

Comment: i already initialized it here `int pos=0,ch;` , and globally defined `struct plan *headptr, *newptr, *curptr, *prevptr;`

Comment: note that the values of `ch` and `act` are undefined values.
The automatic variable declare (and also `malloc`) does not set a specific value.

Comment: "I already initialized it..." - [turn up your compiler warnings, dude](https://pastebin.com/TijBcaep). You initialized `pos`, not `ch`. Turn up your compiler warnings to pedantic levels and *fix* the issues flagged, then *run your code in a debugger*.

Comment: owh sorry i misunderstood initialized as define, so `ch=1` , that wasnt the problem but thx, it still works cause if ch is not defined it is still not equal to 0. loop still works but the ghost still remains. however i still dont understand this part though "newptr->act at if (newptr->act==NULL)" @bluepixy ,,// my compiler warnings are on, and the program runs but iam only using codeblocks it does not show some errors like wrong type define or initiallzation.@whozcraig

Comment: So where is the part of your code that sets `NULL` to `newptr->act`?

Comment: owh... thx dude!!! @BLUEPIXY ....teaching the whole way throough, thx for ur patience and wisdom!!

Answer (score 0):

The answer was given by BLUEPIXY in a comment:
Set `NULL` to `newptr->act`.

Comment: "i dont know how to mark my question as answered remind me cause i cant answer my own question in 2 days", This is not important.

Comment: Questions get treated as "answered" when they have an answer, which yours now has. There is no mechanism to do that directly.